# Android openGL attempt to increase FPS by using the same vertices for multiple meshes

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing a game where similar objects are rendered on the screen. The problem is that every time a new object is added, more vertices needs to be handled, so FPS decrease.

Since I am a beginner with openGl, I have some general ideas about improving performance, I just don't know what openGl allows me to do.

1. Since most of my objects are identical(same number of vertices, same colors, same uvs and same normals), but only the position and rotation of the objects are different, is it possible to send the vertices for similar objects only once, on each frame render , and then call drawElements for all objects and modify only the objects positions?
2. Is it possible to go even further, and upload those similar vertices, only once when the scene is 1st created, and on each frame render just call drawElements for each object?

Currently, I am sending the vertices for each object like this:

```
.......
gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colors);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef(position);
gl.glRotatef(rotation);
gl.glScalef(scale);    
gl.glDrawElements(renderType,nr,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, faces);
gl.glPopMatrix();
........
```

I am thinking I should do someting like this:

```
.......
gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colors);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
for(eachObject)
{
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef(position);
gl.glRotatef(rotation);
gl.glScalef(scale);
gl.glDrawElements(renderType,nr,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, faces);
gl.glPopMatrix();
........
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes (even better)

Your second code example looks exactly like what you should be doing.

There's no reason you'd need to upload the vertices more than once, doing it on initialization should be sufficient. After that just set the pointers any time you want to render. You can call glDrawElements as many times as you want with different translations/rotations.

Comment: But I still don't understand. Setting the vertexPointer on each frame render, doesn't mean those vertices will be uploaded to GPU every time? If you say 2 is even possible, I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: Calling the *Pointer functions does not upload any data, it just tells OpenGL where the data exists. You can use pointers in two ways: 1) as Vertex Arrays, in which the vertices are streamed to GPU on every draw elements call (you don't want this). or 2) As a vertex buffer object (VBO), where you create a vertex buffer on GPU at initialization, and point to it with *Pointer. Then when draw elements is called, the data is loaded from the on GPU memory. Anyway read this: http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/opengl_vbo.php , it will help you to understand. @Mihaisiatat

Comment: Your answer has helped me understand what are my options. Seems VBO's are not working on Android 2.2 (due to some bugs in their android framework).An alternative is to use libgdx. But for now I will implement point 1 for 2.2, while for 2.3 and greater I will use VBOs as well(point 2). Thanks for your help.